# Running a system command in a perl script that has "@" character

Tags: perl

I have a system command like this :

```
unix_command "@output_file path_to_file"
```

Now when I try `exec` or `system` commands in a perl script I get this error :

> Getting a string when expecting an operator.

Can you please help me how to do it in Perl.

Appreciate your help.

Thanks a ton! 
Rakesh

Comment: You can simply escape the `@` with a backslash. eg: `system "echo \@this";`

Comment: `unix_command "@output_file path_to_file"` doesn't look right to me. You sure it's not `unix_command "@output_file" "path_to_file"`? I assumed you meant the latter in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

`system` is really two different functions.

### You can use it to launch a program.

The following syntax are used to launch a program:

```
system($prog, @one_or_more_args)
system({ $prog }, $arg0, @args)
```

Using one of these syntax, all strings passed as arguments are passed untouched to the child program.

Example usage:

```
system('perl', '-e', 'my @a = "foo"; print "@a\n";');
```

### You can use it to execute a shell command.

The following syntax are used to execute a shell command:

```
system($shell_cmd)
```

The above is short for

```
system('/bin/sh', '-c', $shell_cmd)
```

You must provide a valid shell command. It you are building the command, you will need to take care to properly escape anything that needs escaping.

Example usage:

```
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

my $cmd = shell_quote('perl', '-e', 'my @a = "foo"; print "@a\n";');
system($cmd);
```

---

A bit more specifically to your case, the shell command

```
program @file1 file2
```

can be executed as follows:

```
system('program', '@'.$file1, $file2);
```

If you actually need to construct a shell command (e.g. because you want to redirect output), you can use the following:

```
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

my $cmd = shell_quote('program', '@'.$file1, $file2) . ' >output.txt 2>&1';
system($cmd);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need interpolation, use single quotes.

```
system 'echo @a';
```

If you do, use backslash.

```
system "echo \@a";
```